# Finding the points of intersection in Polar Equations

Tags: calculus

I must find the area of the region that lies inside the first curve and outside the second curve for:

$ r^2 = 8cos2\theta, r = 2$

How do I find $a$ and $b$? My solution manual tells me that the curves intersect when $cos2\theta = 1/2$ but I don't see where that came from. I tried setting it equal to each other, but keep getting $1/4$.

Comment: Did you notice the $r^2$ in the first curve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The curves will intersect if $8\cos2\theta$ is positive (since it equals $r^2$) and equals 4 (because $r=2$ so $r^2=2^2=4$).

[I emphasize that it must be positive, because for example $r=8\cos2\theta$ and $r=2$ intersect whenever $8\cos2\theta=2$ and also when $8\cos2\theta=-2$.]

Anyway, $8\cos2\theta=4$ gives us $\cos2\theta=4/8=1/2$. This gives us the needed values of $\theta$.

Comment: Andres, or to anyone else, I also have a question related to this problem. When I enter this equation into my ti-83, the leminiscate never completely closes its loop. Any suggestions how to do so?

Answer (score 0):

my answer for this is like this,,

since r^2=8cosθ , a graph of this is lemniscate!
  *symmetric wrt x-axis.

Comment: This answer can use some cleanup (MathJax) and clarification. Regards